# Jquery: Why is function returning global var when calling a function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I don't understand why is the following code returning 1 and not 10. Could u please explain? Thank u!

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    function foo() { }
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

Comment: one word ... hoisting

Comment: Could u describe it more, please?

Comment: @VeryCurious Can you search `variable hoisting` please? Doesn't matches with your name `Very Curious`(I doubt)

Comment: Hoisting is JavaScript's default behaviour of moving all declarations to the top of the current scope (to the top of the current script or the current function). - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: I guess the inner foo refers to the foo function, if u remove the foo function, then u get 10. Hoisting, cool , didnt know that.

Comment: @JaromandaX Never use `w3schools` see http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: **Never** is a strong term :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that's why I used it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), your function

```
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    function foo() { }
}
```

is translated as

```
function bar() {
    var foo; // hoisted variable declaration
    foo = 10; // now it is a number with value 10
    return; // here the function stops executing
    foo = function foo() { }; // now the variable *would* be a function, but this code is never reached
}
```

hence, the global is not overwritten.

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

Comment: shouldnt it be `foo = function (){ }` in last line

Comment: I'm not sure about it, I think it retains the name too.

Comment: If I place alert(typeof foo); at the end of function bar(), according to this it should return function, right? But it returns number... Seems like I don't really understand the hoisting of the function foo() { } ...

Comment: If you place the `alert()` after `return`, you shouldn't see anything at all; if you place it before, `foo` is still a number, and that is why you see that.

Comment: @VeryCurious see the edit with some explanation comments.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `function foo() { }` works. It happens by [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Demo. https://jsfiddle.net/t3ehq7h7/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share what you want function foo() to do; removing it will update the value of foo.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/p8pdL134/6/

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    //function foo() { }
}    
bar();
alert(foo);
```